# Show first image from WooCommerce product's gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having some problems trying to show the first image of a gallery product on WooCommerce.

I'm working on a personal WordPress theme, with personal template, all this work is to build an OWL carousel to show every product on a different slide.

I'm new with WooCommerce, I'm using `WP_Query` to show the products of a category, inside of this while loop I'm showing `the_title`, `the_content`, `the_permalink` of every product. I want to show the first and only one image from the gallery of every product but I don't know how to get it.

Here's my code so far:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="carousel">
        <?php 
          $params = array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'        => '-1',
            'product_cat'           => 'barras'
          );

          $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
          if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
            while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
              $wc_query->the_post();
              ?>
              <div class="item">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="prev"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/prev.png" alt=""></a>
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="next"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/next.png" alt=""></a>
                  <p class="titulo-producto-slider"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                </a>
                <div class="espacio-10"></div>
                <div class="descripcion-producto-slider">
                  <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="ver-detalle">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Ver detalles</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
          <?php
            endwhile;
              wp_reset_postdata();
          else:  ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'No Products' );?></p> 
          <?php endif;
        ?>
      </div>
```

Sorry if you don't understand something, it is my first question on Stack Overflow and I don't speak English.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

// Product has an image gallery, get first image
if ( is_array( $attachment_ids ) && ! empty( $attachment_ids ) ) {
    $first_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_ids[0] );
    // ... then do whatever you need to do with it
}
// Product has no gallery
else {
    // To-Do
}
```

For more details: [WP_Product class reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html).